# How could I rewrite this CallExpression non-recursively?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, javacc

I am currently working on [JavaCC grammar](https://github.com/highsource/javascript-codemodel/blob/master/parser/src/main/javacc/ecmascript-262.jj) for [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf). I'm somewhat new to JavaCC so would appreciate some help with the following question.

**§ 11.2 Left-Hand-Side Expressions** defines the following `CallExpression` production:

```
CallExpression :
    MemberExpression Arguments
    CallExpression Arguments
    CallExpression [ Expression ]
    CallExpression . IdentifierName
```

This is *left* recursive and therefore does not work in JavaCC as is.

I am thinking of rewriting it as follows (`.jj`-similar pseudocode):

```
CallExpression :
  MemberExpression Arguments ( Arguments | "[" Expression "]" | "." IdentifierName )*
```

**Is this the correct rewriting?**

Comment: The problem is not that the rule is recursive. The problem is that it is left recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a correct rewriting.  In general

```
A --> B | A C
```

can be rewritten as

```
A --> B (C)*
```